# Docker images -a showing several images with repository <none>

Tags: docker

When I use command `docker ps -a` it lists several images with repository `<none>`.  I'm assuming they're related to another image given the similar time stamp.  I'm just wondering what their purpose is?

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
opensuse            latest              33ab078b606b        5 days ago          254.6 MB
mattgruter/drone    latest              ec2ee19cb579        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              69d95bd4b1f9        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              227d0f1e0dfa        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              a19dbed68faa        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              01ff591e80dc        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              89c0c546d2ba        2 weeks ago         312.4 MB
<none>              <none>              030d18544ee4        2 weeks ago         279.1 MB
<none>              <none>              1aaa2da8e8c2        2 weeks ago         271.6 MB
<none>              <none>              c7928e43d1b3        2 weeks ago         269.9 MB
<none>              <none>              0252973e04f0        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              2004ab1a6ca0        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              c26aae018d13        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              5707a16ae741        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              d959a0f0afef        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              bd654a62529d        2 weeks ago         268.6 MB
<none>              <none>              bd52fe5f72a3        2 weeks ago         220.6 MB
<none>              <none>              cd074038dbb7        2 weeks ago         209.2 MB
<none>              <none>              4c12a68b82b3        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              f272e06028fd        2 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              6d4946999d4f        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              9fd3c8c9af32        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              435050075b3f        3 weeks ago         188.3 MB
<none>              <none>              428b411c28f0        3 weeks ago         188.1 MB
<none>              <none>              5b8dd08af89b        10 weeks ago        0 B
```

Answer (score 2):

<del>When you build an image docker creates temporary container to move from one step to another.</del>
However these *"< none >" images* are something else; they are created when you build an image with the same repository/tag as one that has already been pulled. They are called **dangling/untagged** images.
You can clean them up via:

```
docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)
```

Comment: And that's the same for images that I simply pull from the docker hub?  Do these temporary containers ever go away, or do they just take up disk space?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Temporary containers are not untagged images.  Yes, they are just cached in your file system so they will take disk space until you remove them.

Comment: I tried deleting them, but docker returned an error saying they were all used by my drone container.

Comment: Did you built your "drone" container yourself ? The "< none >"  images are used by the intermediate containers that still exist from building the "drone" image.

Comment: No, I just did a `docker run -e DRONE_GITHUB_CLIENT="..." -e DRONE_GITHUB_SECRET="..." -p 8080:80 --privileged mattgruter/drone` and it pulled down the image from the Docker registry.